# Retrofit image is uploaded but empty server response is returned

Tags: android, web-services, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm not able to get a response using retrofit, while it gives a success response as:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=201, message=Created, url=http://test.some_url.in/api/upload/user/PostUserImage/}
```

and the image is successfully uploaded to server but
Nothing is shown either in response body or using Gson:

I'm using the following code:

```
private void uploadImage(byte[] imageBytes) {

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);

RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), imageBytes);

MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", "unnamed.jpg", requestFile);
Call<Response> call = retrofitInterface.uploadImage(body);
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Log.v("keys","-----response---------"+response);
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

            Response responseBody = response.body();
            mBtImageShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            assert responseBody != null;

        } else {

            ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            assert errorBody != null;
            Response errorResponse = gson.fromJson(errorBody.toString(), Response.class);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {

        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
});
}
```

Please tell me how can I get the server response.....

Comment: is your api returns response?

Comment: yes it returns when I'm doing in ARC client, it returns in JSON array as 

[ Image Uploaded Successfully ] 
but when using retrofit code, the image gets uploaded but response only has 

Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=201, message=Created, url=http://test.some_url.in/api/upload/user/PostUserImage/}

Comment: The HTTP 201 Created success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded and has led to the creation of a resource, so take that 201 as success response. - https://restfulapi.net/http-status-201-created/

Comment: Thanks, @HemantSharma but how can I get the server response??? any idea, i have used HttpLoggingInterceptor and OkHttpClient as well as suggested by Divyanshu. But still, nothing is returned in logcat....

Comment: Frist print response before using response body or error body. In response.body you can find **response.body.string()**  same ase errorBody. and print the String output. you can get what outpur are coming.

Comment: @TariqulIslam sorry sir it's not getting clear from your comment what should I do!!!!!!

this thing i have already tried
 Response res = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Response.class); but it crashed saying            com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING                                                            
                                                                                                                          try adding some code if you really want to help

Comment: For showing response in logcat you have to follow some  things before using GSON or other things.

`if (response.isSuccessful()) {
Log.v("response","response: "+response.body.string());
}else{
Log.e("response","error: "+response.errorBody.string());
}`

you have to use `string()` not `toString()`

But if want convert the response in GSON it will be problem because may be you don't know what is the actual response format

Comment: ok sir thanks ill try it but i think only string is not supported or it shows error!!!

Comment: First, comment out your GSON code. try to my code. see the what is the response look like. You got an exception because Gson failed to convert the response

Comment: string() method needs a `try catch` . just use a `try catch`

Comment: thanks for your help sir but it says following errors:  body has private access in retrofit2.Response and same for errorBody even after try catch.
it has to be response.body().toString() if I'm not wrong

Comment: if (response.isSuccessful()) {try {Log.v("response", "response: " + response.body().toString());} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}} else { try { Log.e("response", "error: " + response.errorBody().string());} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();} } this prints folowing response in successful block:  com.test.uploadfile.Response@9bb5517      how can i print string response

Comment: @Override
public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        try {
            Log.e("LOG", "Retrofit Response: " + response.body.string()); //for printing the response in logs
   if (response.code() == 201) {
   // Do some stuff
   } else {
   // Something else
   }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Comment: use 2.6.0 version for retrofit. And I mentiond not use `toString()` use only `string()`

Comment: @TariqulIslam here 
if (response.isSuccessful()) { 
Log.v("response","response: "+response.body.string()); }//shows compile time error Cannot resolve symbol 'string' while working fine for else block

else {  Log.e("response", "error: " + response.errorBody().string());
                }

Comment: Here is my code `try {
                        response.body().string();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }`
You miss body()

Comment: @TariqulIslam Sorry but I've already tried that   Log.v("response", "response: " + response.body().string()); but here it shows error Cannot resolve method string().

Comment: Show your full  code what you did.

Comment: Update your response  like `public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response)` 
to 
`public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response)` and also relative area

Comment: Change your response type like upper comment. Response to ResponseBody

Comment: @TariqulIslam  Thanks your solution worked like charm... Please post it as your answer. I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the correct **raw** response (**Error** or **Success**) from server use `ResponseBody` as a generic class of `Response`

So you can update your code like:

```
 Call<ResponseBody> call = retrofitInterface.uploadImage(body);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

           // Log.v("keys","-----response---------"+response);
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

               // Response responseBody = response.body();
                //mBtImageShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //assert responseBody != null;

                 try{
                Log.d("response","data: "+response.body().string())
              }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                  }

            } else {

               // ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();

                //Gson gson = new Gson();

                //assert errorBody != null;
                //Response errorResponse = gson.fromJson(errorBody.toString(), Response.class);


            try{
               Log.e("response","error: "+response.errorBody().string())
              }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

I hope you will get the correct response

Comment: Thanks @Tariqul Islam it really worked like a charm.

Comment: Welcome. I commented on your code. you can change it perform your desire operation according your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpLoggingInterceptor` for print whole request and response in logcat

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
                    .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build();
```

for logging-interceptor

`implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'`

In `RequestBody` you pass `File` instead of Byte Array

```
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), imageBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sir can you explain how can I use this okHttpClient object to print the whole request.

Comment: all activities happens in network request or response it complete print in logcat in verbose mode

Comment: Sorry, sir, I have used HttpLoggingInterceptor  and OkHttpClient  as use suggested but still, nothing is shown in response.

Comment: In RequestBody you pass File instead of Byte Array